# get data from db and split

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get the data from address field in customer table and split it then store into a variable.

Scenario:

I have 2 tables in database, customer and address.
 [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgj10.png)
I am continuing a project and needed to fix a bug(some customers doesn't have lat and long on the database and giving a default position on the map). The idea is I need to get the address field from customer and split it(maybe not) then compare it to the address field from address table so that I can get the lat and long from the address table.

I am trying to start and wanting to get the data from customer table. But I am getting a 404 error.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection = require('./database/connection.js');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.userId);
    // this small block of code checks to see whether a session is active, which means whether the user is authenticated or not
    // if this is not the case, the user will be redirected to the login form, ensuring they are validated before they are allowed access
    var user = req.session.user,
        userId = req.session.userId;
    console.log(userId);
    //console.log('ddd='+userId);
    if (userId == null) {
        res.redirect("/login");
        return;
    }

    req.app.get('db').query("SELECT * FROM customer", function(err, rows, fields) {
        var customer_list = rows;
        console.log(customer_list);
    })
});
```

Comment: are you getting the 404 when sending the request from a client to the server or from the server to the database?

Comment: how do I check? It says this " the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: How are you testing this? I assume you run the server then send a request with postman, curl or something similar, could be you are writing the wrong path for the request, also check the port, i think it defaults to 3000

Comment: I deployed it locally(localhost:3000/find) then go to the link and I get 404 error

Comment: Have you tried without the `/find`? So far i would think the problem could be on the deployment

Comment: I have, it works and just go straight to the homepage and shows nothing.

Comment: I mean it works and shows no error but shows nothing too.

Comment: does the server prints the logs? from the code given i guess the request executes the route `/` where I dont see you returning anything beside the redirect. if the problem is on `req.app.get('db')` then there could be a problem in some other file where you configure the database, maybe `connection.js`; if that route is not called at all then the problem is also in other file where you define the routes